# Minikube / Docker proxy is using port 80

Tags: minikube, docker-proxy

I am using minikube in no-driver mode ( `sudo minikube start --vm-driver none` ) and I can't free port 80.

With

```
sudo netstat -nlplute
```

I get:

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.14:2380       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          58500      7200/etcd           
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          62030      8681/docker-proxy   
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          57318      8656/docker-proxy
```

I tried to stop minikube, but it doesn't seem to be working when using `driver=none`

How should I free port 80 ?

EDIT: Full netstat ouput

```
➜  ~ sudo netstat -nlpute   
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      102        35399      1019/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          6629864    11358/cupsd         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      128        45843      1317/postgres       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6942          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       14547489   16086/java          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10248         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          58474      1053/kubelet        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10249         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          71361      10409/kube-proxy    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45801         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          57445      1053/kubelet        
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.14:2379       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          56922      7920/etcd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          56921      7920/etcd           
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.14:2380       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          56917      7920/etcd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2381          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          56084      7920/etcd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:63342         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       14549242   16086/java          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          15699      1/init              
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10257         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          60857      7889/kube-controlle 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10259         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          56932      7879/kube-scheduler 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          48507      2205/teamviewerd    
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          6629863    11358/cupsd         
tcp6       0      0 :::8443                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          55158      7853/kube-apiserver 
tcp6       0      0 :::44444                :::*                    LISTEN      1000       16217187   7252/___go_build_gi 
tcp6       0      0 :::32028                :::*                    LISTEN      0          74556      10409/kube-proxy    
tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*                    LISTEN      0          58479      1053/kubelet        
tcp6       0      0 :::30795                :::*                    LISTEN      0          74558      10409/kube-proxy    
tcp6       0      0 :::10251                :::*                    LISTEN      0          56926      7879/kube-scheduler 
tcp6       0      0 :::10252                :::*                    LISTEN      0          60851      7889/kube-controlle 
tcp6       0      0 :::30285                :::*                    LISTEN      0          74559      10409/kube-proxy    
tcp6       0      0 :::31406                :::*                    LISTEN      0          74557      10409/kube-proxy    
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          15702      1/init              
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          16269016   16536/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          16263128   16524/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 :::10256                :::*                    LISTEN      0          75123      10409/kube-proxy    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:45455           0.0.0.0:*                           115        40296      1082/avahi-daemon:  
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           1000       16274723   23811/chrome --type 
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           1000       16270144   23728/chrome        
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           1000       16270142   23728/chrome        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           115        40294      1082/avahi-daemon:  
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           102        35398      1019/systemd-resolv 
udp        0      0 192.168.0.14:68         0.0.0.0:*                           0          12307745   1072/NetworkManager 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           0          18653      1/init              
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           0          6628156    11360/cups-browsed  
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                115        40295      1082/avahi-daemon:  
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                0          15705      1/init              
udp6       0      0 :::50342                :::*                                115        40297      1082/avahi-daemon:
```

Comment: What minikube and kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: minikube version: v1.6.2, kubect client: v1.18, kubectl server v1.17

Comment: When a container starts with its port forwarded to the Docker host on which it runs, in addition to the new process that runs inside the container, you may have noticed an additional process on the Docker host called `docker-proxy`. Its clean minikube or you have there any deployment, svc, ingress? What you want to achieve? Could you share whole output of `netstat -nlplute`?

Comment: full netstat output joined in question. Sorry for delay !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking that my port 8080 was also used by docker proxy, I did

```
   $ docker ps
```

and notices that both port 80 and port 8080 are used by traefik controller:

```
$ kubectl get services

traefik-ingress-service   ClusterIP   10.96.199.177   <none>        80/TCP,8080/TCP   25d
```

When I checked for traefik service, I found:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-service
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      name: web
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      name: admin
```

So, I think this is why I get a docker-proxy. If I need it to use another port, I can change it here. My bad :(

Answer (score 1):

Ive reproduced your environment (`--vm-driver=none`). At first I thought it might be connected with `minikube` built-in configuration, however clean Minikube don't use port 80 on default configuration.

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.0", GitCommit:"9e991415386e4cf155a24b1da15becaa390438d8", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-25T14:58:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:12:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
$ minikube version
minikube version: v1.6.2

$ sudo netstat -nlplute
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10257         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          49556      9345/kube-controlle 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10259         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          50223      9550/kube-scheduler 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      101        15218      752/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          21550      1541/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:44197         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          51016      10029/kubelet       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10248         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          51043      10029/kubelet       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10249         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          52581      10524/kube-proxy    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          49728      9626/etcd           
tcp        0      0 10.156.0.11:2379        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          49727      9626/etcd           
tcp        0      0 10.156.0.11:2380        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          49723      9626/etcd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2381          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          49739      9626/etcd           
tcp6       0      0 :::10256                :::*                    LISTEN      0          52577      10524/kube-proxy    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          21552      1541/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::8443                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          49120      9419/kube-apiserver 
tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*                    LISTEN      0          51050      10029/kubelet       
tcp6       0      0 :::10251                :::*                    LISTEN      0          50217      9550/kube-scheduler 
tcp6       0      0 :::10252                :::*                    LISTEN      0          49550      9345/kube-controlle 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           101        15217      752/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 10.156.0.11:68          0.0.0.0:*                           100        15574      713/systemd-network 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           0          23984      2059/chronyd        
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                0          23985      2059/chronyd
```

Good description for what `docker-proxy` is used you can check [this article](https://windsock.io/the-docker-proxy/).

> When a container starts with its port forwarded to the Docker host on which it runs, in addition to the new process that runs inside the container, you may have noticed an additional process on the Docker host called docker-proxy

This `docker-proxy` might be something similar like `docker zombie process` where container was removed, however allocated port wasn't unlocked. Unfortunately it seems that this is recurrent docker issue occuring across versions and OS since 2016. As I mentioned  I think currently there is no fix for this, however you can find workaround.

```
cd /usr/libexec/docker/
ln -s docker-proxy-current docker-proxy
service docker restart
===
$ sudo service docker stop
$ sudo service docker start
===
$ sudo service docker stop
# remove all internal docker network: rm /var/lib/docker/network/files/
$ sudo service docker start
===
$ sudo systemctl stop docker 
$ sudo systemctl start docker
```

There are a few github threads mentioning about this issue. For more information please check [this](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3277) and [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25981) thread.

Comment: I think I found the issue, traefik controller is using those 2 ports. But thanks for your answer, I found very useful to read more about docker proxy